# Android Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: android, exception

When I use this code:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
```

there is always an error, any ideas? Running on an android virtual device

```
W/System.err(3211): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174)
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247)
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190)
W/System.err(3211):     at com.example.executeandroidtest.ShellUtils.execCommand(MainActivity.java:661)
W/System.err(3211):     at com.example.executeandroidtest.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:410)
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err(3211): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
W/System.err(3211):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
W/System.err(3211):     ... 6 more
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious? You want to get super user privileges but android has Security restrictions.

Comment: So, how can I solve it?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Probably SELinux is enforcing some policy to deny root access

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

1. find where su is, for instance: `/system/xbin/su`
2. check su's file permission: `ls -al /system/xbin/su`
3. change mod if necessary: `chmod 4755 su`
4. try again.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
```

Comment: I've added this, but still this issue.